# Sending asp.net Page over email from windows Service Application

Tags: asp.net, windows

following is code written in asp.net web form, to execute and send aspx page over email:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
Server.Execute("ResetPasswordEmailContents.aspx?UserID=" + user.ProviderUserKey.ToString(), htw);
return MailManager.SendEmail(txtEmail.Text, String.Empty, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailPasswordRecoverySubject"], sw.ToString());
```

What I want to do now is to send this email from a windows service application, I can not use the "Server.Execute()" Method in windows form application. Any one have Idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what ResetPasswordEmailContents.aspx does.

I'd use [SmtpClient](http://www.intstrings.com/ramivemula/articles/how-to-send-an-email-using-c-net-with-complete-features/) to send the message. I also wrote a post on [templating with the Spark view engine from a WPF app/windows service](http://www.leghumped.com/2012/12/28/templating-with-spark-and-wpf/) which may help you.

Comment: "ResetPasswordEmailContents.aspx" is the page that I want to be displayed in the user inbox check this one Ihttp://screencast.com/t/WE8aZGLk.